# Make sql query run faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

Is it possible to make some optimization on such query ?

```
with t (CurrentPrice, [Weight])
as ( select CurrentPrice, [Weight] from SomeTable where GroupingId = SomeBigIntId )

SELECT MaxExactPrice = ( select MAX(CurrentPrice) FROM t Where [Weight] > 0 ),  
   MinExactPrice = ( select MIN(CurrentPrice) FROM t Where [Weight] > 0 ),
   MaxSimilarPrice = ( select MAX(CurrentPrice) FROM t Where [Weight] = 0 ),
   MinSimilarPrice = ( select MIN(CurrentPrice) FROM t Where [Weight] = 0 ),
   ExactCount = ( select Count(*) FROM t Where [Weight] > 0 ),
   SimilarCount = ( select Count(*) FROM t Where [Weight] = 0 ),
   Count(*) as TotalCount
FROM t
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why to use a `CTE` here ?  You can write the `where` clause in the outer select query

Comment: Could you give a sample ?

Comment: @user2484625: A recommendaion, use SET STATISTICS IO ON, execution plan to tune this type of query. Again it also depends on the amount of data present in the table you are querying and the available indexes on it as well. Without this knowledge it would be difficult for others to optimise this query for you. (If i am correct)

Comment: That query can be organized in so many different ways, you'd just have to test them. There's nothing obviously wrong there that I can see though. But if there's a performance issue there, I would create an index on GroupId & Weight, with CurrentPrice as included column, filtered by where GroupingId IS NOT NULL (and reworking the query filter, also add Weight >= 0 to index filter). Depends on what other data there is in there and what other queries may be using those fields, but that's a good place to start at least. :)

Comment: Yes, I already have such index. And honestly there is no any performance issues yet (but I didn't test it on large amount of data). I'm not so good with sql, so I'd prefer to know - is there any ways to wrote such query simply and maybe the execution plan will look simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead. this way you do not have to hit same table 8 different times.

```
select MAX(CASE WHEN [Weight] > 0 THEN CurrentPrice ELSE NULL END) AS MaxExactPrice
,MIN(CASE WHEN [Weight] > 0 THEN CurrentPrice ELSE NULL END) AS MinExactPrice
,MAX(CASE WHEN [Weight] = 0 THEN CurrentPrice ELSE NULL END) AS MaxSimilarPrice
,MIN(CASE WHEN [Weight] = 0 THEN CurrentPrice ELSE NULL END) AS MinSimilarPrice
,COUNT(CASE WHEN [Weight] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS ExactCount
,COUNT(CASE WHEN [Weight] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS SimilarCount
,COUNT(*)AS TotalCount
from SomeTable where GroupingId = SomeBigIntId
```